# RecyclerView image change on click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm making ola like car selecting function. In my case the car detais such as car type (mini,micro), car select image and car unselect image are stored in sqlite and then i read the db and store the car selection details in a horizontal recycle view. Every thing works fine , but i'm not able to select on particular car .When I select another image it changes to selected image but previously selected one doesn't changes to unselected image. Can anyone help me to fix this issue.

below is my recycler adapter

```
public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder> {

ListItemClickListener mlistener;
Context mCtx;
Cursor mCursor;
private int clickposition = 0;


public RecycleAdapter(Context context, ListItemClickListener listener) {
    mCtx = context;
    mlistener = listener;
}

@Override
public RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_vehicles_available, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    String carType = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SERVICE));
    holder.carType.setText(carType);

    byte[] image = mCursor.getBlob(mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_IMAGE));
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    holder.carImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mCursor == null)
        return 0;
    return mCursor.getCount();
}

public void swapCursor(Cursor data) {
    mCursor = data;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public interface ListItemClickListener {

    void onClickListener(int position);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView carType;

    ImageView carImage;
    RelativeLayout rl;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        carType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtcarType);
        carImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.select_carImage);
        rl = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rl);
        rl.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.rl:
                clickposition = getAdapterPosition();
                Log.d("clickposition", String.valueOf(clickposition));
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < mCursor.getCount(); i++) {

                    int id = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbContract.DbEntry._ID));
                    mlistener.onClickListener(id);
                    if (clickposition != i) {
                        mCursor.moveToPosition(i);
                        Log.d("clickposition1", String.valueOf(i));
                        byte[] image = mCursor.getBlob(mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_IMAGE));
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
                        carImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                    mCursor.moveToPosition(i);
                    Log.d("clickposition2", String.valueOf(i));
                    byte[] image_sel = mCursor.getBlob(mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_IMAGE_SELECTED));
                    Bitmap bitmap_sel = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image_sel, 0, image_sel.length);
                    carImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap_sel);

                }

                Toast.makeText(mCtx, "driverlocation = Firebase.getreference" + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SERVICE)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }

}

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNNJt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your onBindViewholder to this,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecycleAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
String carType = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SERVICE));
holder.carType.setText(carType);

byte[] image = mCursor.getBlob(mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_IMAGE));
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
holder.carImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

holder.rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            clickposition = position;
            Log.d("clickposition", String.valueOf(clickposition));
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < mCursor.getCount(); i++) {

                int id = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbContract.DbEntry._ID));
                mlistener.onClickListener(id);
                if (clickposition != i) {
                    mCursor.moveToPosition(i);
                    Log.d("clickposition1", String.valueOf(i));
                    byte[] image = mCursor.getBlob(mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_IMAGE));
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
                    carImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
                mCursor.moveToPosition(i);
                Log.d("clickposition2", String.valueOf(i));
                byte[] image_sel = mCursor.getBlob(mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_IMAGE_SELECTED));
                Bitmap bitmap_sel = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image_sel, 0, image_sel.length);
                carImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap_sel);

            }

            Toast.makeText(mCtx, "driverlocation = Firebase.getreference" + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SERVICE)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

   }
```